# How to loop to remove all instance of an value from same array?

Tags: c#

I have two different arrays for my form as follows:

```
int[] X = { 14, 19, 24, 28, 33 };
int[] Y = { 90, 131, 132, 150, 170 };
```

And I can remove one value from both array (same index number) using:

```
 int maxValue = Y[0];
 for (int i = 1; i < Y.Length; i++)
 {
      if (Y[i] > maxValue)
      maxValue = Y[i]; // max value in the array.

 }

 if (maxValue < 100)                                    
 {
     int indexY = IndexOfInt(Y, maxValue);
     Y = Y.Except(new int[] { maxValue }).ToArray();
     List<int> Z = X.ToList();
     Z.RemoveAt(indexY);
     X = Z.ToArray();
 }

static int IndexOfInt(int[] arr, int value) //finds the index number  
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] == value)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;

        }
```

The code above returns:

```
int[] X = { 19, 24, 28, 33 };
int[] Y = { 131, 132, 150, 170 };
```

How do I go about and remove multiple instances of the same value, lets say

```
int[] X = { 14, 19, 24, 28, 33 };
int[] Y = { 90, 90, 132, 150, 170 };
```

I'm guessing it has to be a `while` loop but just can't get the loop or the concept right. It's not about avoiding duplicates. Its about removing all the values that is `<100`. I want to get rid of values that is less than 100 from `X` array from, for example:

```
int[] Y = { 90, 90, 132, 150, 170 };
```

should be

```
int[] Y = { 132, 150, 170 };
```

And because we are removing `X[0]` `X[1]` we have to remove `Y[0]` `Y[1]`

```
int[] X = { 24, 28, 33 };
```

As I have to use this array to create an `Chart` in my form. I Hope this clear things up for `Why`.

Comment: @Grant Winney Yes `List<int>` is fine

Comment: What about HashSet<int>? Or even a SortedSet<int>? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx) If you want to avoid duplicates, this seems like a good option.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? what does `X` have to do with `Y`? What values should be removed? why are you using a temporary list `Z` when all you do is remove an item and then assign back to the same list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to remove the instances of values which lower than 100 in Y and corresponding values which has same index number in X. i.e my code removes Y[0] and X[0]

The following code gets the indexes of all elements in `Y` that are less than 100 (minus those indexes that don't exist in `X`, assuming it's possible for `X` to be shorter than `Y`), then removes the elements at all of those indexed positions from both `X` and `Y`:

```
var X = new List<int> { 14, 19, 24, 28, 33 };
var Y = new List<int> { 90, 90, 132, 150, 170 };

var indexes = Y.Select((element, index) => new {element, index})
               .Where(item => item.element < 100
                              && item.index < X.Count)
               .Select(item => item.index)
               .OrderByDescending(i => i)
               .ToList();

foreach (var index in indexes)
{
    X.RemoveAt(index);
    Y.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

The collections will end up with { 24, 28, 33 } and { 132, 150, 170 } in them.

Comment: @Grant no I'm trying to remove the instances of values which lower than 100 in `Y` and corresponding values which has same index number in `X`. i.e my code removes `Y[0]` and `X[0]`

Comment: Works... But I had to do this to create the `Chart`

       `int[] A = X.ToArray();`
       `int[] B = Y.ToArray();`
       `int Z = A.Length;`

      `for (int i = 0; i < Z ; i++)`
      `{`
     `this.chart1.Series["Heart Rate"].Points.AddXY(A[i], B[i]);
      }`

Thanks mate... And how do you check the length? If you can add that too please.

Answer (score 2):

How about the [Distinct<TSource> method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
int[] Y = { 90, 90, 132, 150, 170 };
Y = Y.Distinct().ToArray();
Console.Write("Distinct values: ");
foreach(int d in Y)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ",d);
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Resulting output: `Distinct values: 90 132 150 170`

Comment: you didn't remove the index in the `X`list though.

Comment: @Edmund that wont do.. as I have to use `Y.Length` and `X.Length` on my  project and your code will return `4` for `Y.Length` and what I'm trying to accomplish is that it should return 132 150 170 and `4` for `Y.Length` ps: its a `WinForm` solution.

Comment: @envyM6 You keep mentioning this is WinForms, but your posted problem has nothing to do with WinForms.  It's just c# code.

Comment: @envyM6 Please edit your question and explain what you're trying to do. Clearly, you want something more than just eliminating duplicates from an array of integers, but I can't tell **what** that something more is.

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe Question Updated